# argoCD - external access with ingress not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer, argoproj

I am new at kubernetes so apologies in advance for any silly questions and mistakes. I am trying to setup external access through ingress for ArgoCD. My setup is an aws eks cluster. I have setup alb following the guide [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/tree/v2.2.3/helm/aws-load-balancer-controller). I have also setup external dns service as described [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/blob/v0.9.0/docs/tutorials/aws.md). I also followed the verification steps in that guide and was able to confirm that the dns record got created as well and i was able to access the foo service.

For argoCD I installed the manifests via

```
kubectl create namespace argocd
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/argoproj/argo-cd/stable/manifests/install.yaml -n argocd
```

The argoCD docs mention adding a service to split up http and grpc and an ingress setup [here](https://argoproj.github.io/argo-cd/operator-manual/ingress/#aws-application-load-balancers-albs-and-classic-elb-http-mode). I followed that and installed those as well

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol-version: HTTP2
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: argocd.<mydomain.com>
  labels:
    app: argogrpc
  name: argogrpc
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "443"
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 # Use extensions/v1beta1 for Kubernetes 1.18 and older
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: HTTPS
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/conditions.argogrpc: |
      [{"field":"http-header","httpHeaderConfig":{"httpHeaderName": "Content-Type", "values":["application/grpc"]}}]
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTPS":443}]'
  name: argocd
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  rules:
  - host: argocd.<mydomain.com>
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: argogrpc
            port:
              number: 443
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
      - backend:
          service:
            name: argocd-server
            port:
              number: 443
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - argocd.<mydomain.com>
```

The definitions are applied successfully but I don't see the dns record created neither any external IP listed.  Am I missing any steps or is there any misconfiguration here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you solved this maybe ??

Answer (score 3):

Service type needs to be NodePort.